# Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x8, when calling 'createSocket' from JNI Android 2.3 version only

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm creating the Java Socket from the JNI, attaching the Native thread to Java and creating the socket `createSocket(String, int)`.

This is causing a crash only in Android 2.3.x version and working in above & below versions successfully.

Log as below:

```
09-10 16:10:39.526: E/InputDispatcher(75): channel '40767870 com.x.ClientApp (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
09-10 16:10:39.526: E/InputDispatcher(75): channel '40767870 com.x.ClientApp (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
09-10 16:10:39.556: I/WindowManager(75): WIN DEATH: Window{40811280 com.x.ProvisioningActivity paused=false}
09-10 16:10:39.586: I/WindowManager(75): WIN DEATH: Window{40767870 com.x.ClientApp paused=false}
09-10 16:10:39.616: I/WindowManager(75): WIN DEATH: Window{406b9b98 com.x.ProvisioningActivity paused=false}
09-10 16:10:39.666: E/InputDispatcher(75): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=142, events=0x8
09-10 16:10:39.666: E/InputDispatcher(75): Received spurious receive callback for unknown input channel.  fd=161, events=0x8
```

Issue is 100% in android 2.3.x.

Any ideas?